# In Samsung edge 6 plus String is cropped after two letters

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

In my app Launch screen my app name is cropped in Samsung galaxy s6 edge plus,

[image: Check this screen shot]

Can any one explain why this is happening I checked in other devices it is working fine.
what it should display is Employee but it is showing Em- I don't know why?

Comment: How are we supposed to know without at least your layout being posted?

Comment: @GabeSechan its Relative layout with two text views, it works well in all other devices except in this and it is showing an "-" symbol